# What's better (when it comes to memory usage), Enum integers or an array of integers?

Tags: java, android, arrays, enums, constants

So, I have a `SparseArray` which stores Roboto typefaces.

I have a FontHelper Class which helps me to organize Typefaces and store in a cache.

I have a method to get the typeface I want to:

`public static Typeface getRobotoFont(int fontType, Context context) {}`

The fontType parameter will be an Integer constant which will access the SparseArray. For instance, you want Roboto-Regular, you'd pass the integer `ROBOTO_REGULAR`. My question is, instead of integer constants, would it be better if I just used enums, as in:

```
enum bla {
    ROBOTOREGULAR(0),
    ...
}
```

Comment: Better regarding to what criteria? If you can answer that editing your question, it might stay open.

Comment: @Alfabravo I don't see how this is opinion based. We're talking types, so obviously regarding memory usage.

Comment: 'Obviously' it was not obvious as I can't put anything on hold by myself. If you check, there's not a single mention of "memory usage" in your question. So there's that, edit it and it will come back to life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most important difference is the type checking. **Enums** are checked, **Integer constants** are not.

Comment: Sure, so, would you use enums? In the case of enums, I wouldn't be able to pass a "wrong" value. So it would be more for convenience and for a more readable code than anything, right?

Comment: If you use enums, you address all these problems:
1. Your code won't compile unless you pass valid values in
2. No need for any special "bad input" code - the compiler handles that for you
3. Enum values are unique

ref: http://m.oschina.net/blog/341617

Comment: @Chris Thorna should be marked as right, you really really should check this video to know why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enum, or for a more Android friendly practice, you can use the [IntDef](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) pattern.

Comment: Very interesting as well, but in this case I'm afraid enums is the best option since I'm also going to use XML.